# The table height is stretching the div container which have height defined in percent in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table placed inside a div with overflow:scroll and height specified in percent. It is rendering correctly in chrome with a scrollbar for the div but in IE and Firefox the div is expanding to table height hence generating the scroll bar on web page and stretching it. Please help.

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dijsky/691vg2gb/ (Open it  in chrome first then in IE11, You will find the difference in scrollbar)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <table id="Table1" style="Z-INDEX: 111; LEFT: 16px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 320px; HEIGHT: 240px" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>

                                            <td style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                                            <div style="overflow:scroll;width:100%;height:100%;">                       
                                                <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" rules="all" style="table-layout:fixed;">                             
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td><span>Test</span></td></tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>

                </tr>
            </TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us please. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've added a raw HTML version code. This HTML code is working fine in chrome but having issues with IE and firefox. Thanks for your help.