# Container div doesn't resize correctly in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div that, on Chrome and Firefox, has a scrollbar that works fine. However, when I open it up in Internet Explorer 11, I find that the table inside the div takes up the full height of the screen, with a scrollbar that doesn't work.

My div setup looks like this:

```
   <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main-body-full">
       <div class="table-container">             
         <table>
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th rowspan="2">COLUMN 1</th>
               <th rowspan="2">COLUMN 2</th>
               <th rowspan="2">COLUMN 3</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody id="drawingList">
             /*Filled in with data*/
           </tbody>
          </table>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And the related CSS I'm using:

```
#wrapper{
    /*height: calc(100% - 95px);*/
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

form{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100px;
}

th, td{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
.main-body-full table {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 85%;
    overflow-y: scroll;   
}

/*Adding scrollbar to table body*/ 
.main-body-full tbody {  
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-container {
    height:85%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[An unsolved SO question has a jsFiddle showcasing the exact issue I'm having.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515698/the-table-height-is-stretching-the-div-container-which-have-height-defined-in-pe)

Is there anything I'm missing here? Or does this require a different table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with ie is that it's table cell will always expand to the height of it's content (treating height like min-height).  To get over this all you need is an extra div that is absolutely positioned with the overflow auto, inside a relative div that is 100% height of the td:

```html
<table id="Table1" style="HEIGHT: 240px;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>

    <td style="">
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:relative;">
        <div style="top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; overflow:scroll;position:absolute;">
          <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" rules="all" style="table-layout:fixed;">
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span>Test</span></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</TABLE>
```

PS - I hope this is an email template as using tables for layout like this isn't good, you should be using divs and css

Comment: The absolute positioning was what I needed! Thanks.